# UILabel is resizing on swipe to left (using autolayout and code)

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios6, autolayout

I'm having this weird resizing when I swipe to delete a `UITableCell` subclass (`ExpenseCell`):

[image: Screenshot]

Here's a piece of code I use to resize the `UILabels` according to their contents:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    NSInteger leftMargin = 0;

    if (![descriptionLabel.text isEqualToString:@""]){
        leftMargin = 15;
    }

    CGSize descriptionLabelSize = [descriptionLabel.text sizeWithFont:descriptionLabel.font];
    CGRect descriptionLabelRect = CGRectMake(descriptionLabel.frame.origin.x,
                                         descriptionLabel.frame.origin.y,
                                         descriptionLabelSize.width,
                                         descriptionLabelSize.height);
    descriptionLabel.frame = descriptionLabelRect;

    CGSize categoryLabelSize = [categoryLabel.text sizeWithFont:categoryLabel.font];
    CGRect categoryLabelRect = CGRectMake(descriptionLabel.frame.origin.x + descriptionLabel.frame.size.width + leftMargin,
                                      categoryLabel.frame.origin.y,
                                      categoryLabelSize.width,
                                      categoryLabelSize.height);
    categoryLabel.frame = categoryLabelRect;
}
```

If I comment the code above, I don't have this issue but I lost the autoresizing `UILabels`.

Do you guys have an idea of how to fix this by adding constrains on `AutoLayout` or by changing the existing code?

Thanks in advance!